# How can I move a user's comment to the appropriate place?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/what-are-some-reasons-to-get-or-not-get-a-phd/3318#comment6435_3318) a new user should have added a comment, but mistakenly started a new answer.  Charles (correctly) moved the user's response to be a *comment* rather than an *answer*.  I know Charles is a moderator, which brings me to my question.  Is this sort of maintenance restricted to mods?  Or is this something that I can fix on my own?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's only for mods, but maybe users with high reputation can also do it (although with your reputation, you're already a "trusted user", I don't know if there is a higher level. In any case, that what flags are made for: if you need to move an answer, just flag it "this should be a comment".

Comment: Ah, right.  That's a good solution.

Comment: Yes, "convert to comment" is diamond-only.